# PHP MySQL Date comparison

Tags: php, mysql

I insert a birth date through a text field into a table.
Here I need a mysql query which checks the current month and current date with any of the dates matching in database.
No need to check the year because this is meant for displaying an alert on birthday,
Can any one have the idea of the SQL Query to do this in a single query.. Here I use this with PHP and MySQL. Thanks in Advance

My Sample Code is :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$my_birth_date = "2010-11-08";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mydate WHERE DAYOFMONTH($my_birth_date) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND MONTH($my_birth_date) = MONTH(NOW())
");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['my_name'] . " " . $row['my_dob'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My Table Schema is:
my_name varchar(50)
my_dob date

Date is being stored in table like this format : 2010-01-20 (Year-Month-Day)
Now it is displaying a blank page with out any records, even if i has records matching.
Can any one give some suggestion

Comment: Please provide the CREATE TABLE statement.  If storing a date, the column should be using a DATETIME or DATE data type, not string based because you'll have to convert it to a date related data type before being able to do date operations/comparisons.

Comment: how is the date stored in the database?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

You can find all the Date & Time Functions available in MySQL. You'd probably want to use the DAYOFMONTH and MONTH functions to compare :)

So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYOFMONTH(birthday) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW())
```

There might be some more efficient ways to do this but this is what I'd try first! Hope that helps!

Comment: Hai Gazlion..Thanks for your reply

Comment: You might want to edit your original question with this information. Do you get an error? What does your table schema look like?

Comment: @Gazillion: I have edited my question with updated messages. Can you please have a look

Comment: Well right now you're not comparing with the date of birth in the DB, you're comparing it with a PHP variable. Switch $my_birth_date in your SQL statement with my_dob. The idea is that you're comparing the columns in the your database with the current timestamp.

Comment: @Gazillion: I have replaced the variable as you told. But now also only a blank page is showing. I printed the $result and I got "Resource id #3". What may be the problem?

Comment: @Gazillion: Hi, It works fine for me now. The problem was there was no date which matches with todays date and month.Thanks for the timely help.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code should return all the records in the "mydate" table.

Try the query directly on the server(in a terminal or with an app like phpMyAdmin) to check if it returns data.

Use `mysql_error` to debug your code.

Example :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

mysql_select_db("nonexistentdb", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";

mysql_select_db("kossu", $link);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
?>
```

[mysql_error : php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Then you should see where it crash.